# Hololens Spatial understanding: Transferring coordinates from Unity WebGL app to Hololens Mixed Reality app

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, unity-webgl

i created a simple Unity WebGL application were i visualized room model scanned with Microsoft Hololens.

It looks like this:
[image]

Now i would like to add a landmark (an empty GameObject) to a specific location in the room on my WebGL application, send specific coordinates to my Hololens application and place landmark at the same spot as it was on my WebGL app.

How can i achieve this transformation?
Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: I am not familiar with Hololens but if i am sure you can use markers. You can track a marker create an empty object at that position put all your content as a child to it. Be careful with the pivot though!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WorldAnchorTransferBatch](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/XR.WSA.Sharing.WorldAnchorTransferBatch.html) to persist/load World Anchors to/from Disk.

I've tested this between hololenses, but if your WebGL app uses UnityEngine.XR then it should work